# How to plot categorical variable against a date column in Python

Tags: python-3.x, date, plot, against

I have data that looks like this

```
Date         Fruit
2017-01-01   Orange
2017-01-01   Apple
2017-01-08   Orange
2017-01-09   Orange
2017-01-09   Apple
```

I want to plot Number of Oranges, Number of Apples by Date in a single plot.
How would I do that?

I grouped them by Date and I see the result.

```
df.groupby(['Date','Fruit']).size()
```

```
Date         Fruit
2017-01-01   Orange  1
             Apple   1
2017-01-08   Orange  1
2017-01-09   Orange  1
             Apple   1
```

I tried this but it gives a bar plot having two categories but not against the dates.

```
sns.catplot(x="Fruit", hue="Fruit", kind="count",
            palette="pastel", edgecolor=".6",
            data=df);
```

How can plot a graph have Date on the x-axis and number of apples and the number of oranges for each date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Framing the dataset:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Date", "Fruit"], data=[['2017-01-01','Orange'], ['2017-01-01','Orange'], ['2017-01-01','Apple'], ['2017-01-08','Orange'], ['2017-01-09','Orange'], ['2017-01-09','Apple']])
```

[image: The data looks like this]

By using unstack and group by a bar plot can be drawn:

```
(df
 .groupby(['Date', 'Fruit'])
 .size()
 .unstack()
 .plot.bar()
)
```

[image: Here is the plot by date]

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
# dummy data
date_range = pd.date_range('2019-01-01', '2019-01-06', freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame(['Orange', 'Apple', 'Orange', 'Orange',
                   'Apple', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Orange', 'Orange'],
    index=[date_range[0], date_range[0], date_range[1], date_range[2],
           date_range[2], date_range[2], date_range[2], date_range[3],
           date_range[3]],
    columns=['Fruit'])
df.index.name = 'Date'
```

`groupby` as you do, then `unstack`, which looks like this.

```
>>> print(df.unstack())

Fruit       Apple  Orange
Date                     
2019-01-01    1.0     1.0
2019-01-02    NaN     1.0
2019-01-03    3.0     1.0
2019-01-04    NaN     2.0
```

And then plot the unstacked data.

```
df.unstack().plot(kind='bar')
plt.show()
```

[image]

(You'll have to do something about the date formatting though).

Comment: Hi Chris, Thank you. That made sense. I had tried a similar way and I think it worked. Posting the solution below.