# KeyError: "None of [Index(['23/01/2020' ......,\n dtype='object', length=9050)] are in the [columns]"

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I am learning pandas and matplotlib on my own by using some public dataset via
[this api link](https://api.data.gov.hk/v2/filter?q=%7B%22resource%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.chp.gov.hk%2Ffiles%2Fmisc%2Fenhanced_sur_covid_19_eng.csv%22%2C%22section%22%3A1%2C%22format%22%3A%22json%22%7D)

I'm using colab and below are my codes:

```
import datetime 
import io
import json
import pandas as pd
import requests
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

confirm_resp = requests.get('https://api.data.gov.hk/v2/filterq=%7B%22resource%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.chp.gov.hk%2Ffiles%2Fmisc%2Fenhanced_sur_covid_19_eng.csv%22%2 C%22section%22%3A1%2C%22format%22%3A%22json%22%7D').content

confirm_df = pd.read_json(io.StringIO(confirm_resp.decode('utf-8')))
confirm_df.columns = confirm_df.columns.str.replace(" ", "_")
pd.to_datetime(confirm_df['Report_date'])
confirm_df.columns = ['Case_no', 'Report_date', 'Onset_date', 'Gender', 'Age', 
'Name_of_hospital_admitted', 'Status', 'Resident', 'Case_classification', 'Confirmed_probable']
confirm_df = confirm_df.drop('Name_of_hospital_admitted', axis = 1)
confirm_df.head()
```

and this is what the dataframe looks like:

| Case_no | Report_date | Onset_date | Gender | Age | Status | Resident | Case_classification | Confirmed_probable |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 23/01/2020 | 21/01/2020 | M | 39 | Discharged | Non-HK resident | Imported case | Confirmed |
| 2 | 23/01/2020 | 18/01/2020 | M | 56 | Discharged | HK resident | Imported case | Confirmed |
| 3 | 24/01/2020 | 20/01/2020 | F | 62 | Discharged | Non-HK resident | Imported case | Confirmed |
| 4 | 24/01/2020 | 23/01/2020 | F | 62 | Discharged | Non-HK resident | Imported case | Confirmed |
| 5 | 24/01/2020 | 23/01/2020 | M | 63 | Discharged | Non-HK resident | Imported case | Confirmed |

When I try to make a simple plot with the below code:

```
x = confirm_df['Report_date']
y = confirm_df['Case_classification']
confirm_df.plot(x, y)
```

It gives me the below error:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-e4139a9b5ef1> in <module>()
      4 y = confirm_df['Case_classification']
      5 
----> 6 confirm_df.plot(x, y)
3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    912                 if is_integer(x) and not data.columns.holds_integer():
    913                     x = data_cols[x]
--> 914                 elif not isinstance(data[x], ABCSeries):
    915                     raise ValueError("x must be a label or position")
    916                 data = data.set_index(x)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2910             if is_iterator(key):
   2911                 key = list(key)
-> 2912             indexer = self.loc._get_listlike_indexer(key, axis=1, raise_missing=True)[1]
   2913 
   2914         # take() does not accept boolean indexers
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _get_listlike_indexer(self, key, axis, raise_missing)
   1252             keyarr, indexer, new_indexer = ax._reindex_non_unique(keyarr)
   1253 
-> 1254         self._validate_read_indexer(keyarr, indexer, axis, raise_missing=raise_missing)
   1255         return keyarr, indexer
   1256 
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _validate_read_indexer(self, key, indexer, axis, raise_missing)
   1296             if missing == len(indexer):
   1297                 axis_name = self.obj._get_axis_name(axis)
-> 1298                 raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
   1299 
   1300             # We (temporarily) allow for some missing keys with .loc, except in
KeyError: "*None of [Index(['23/01/2020', '23/01/2020', '24/01/2020', '24/01/2020', '24/01/2020',\n       '26/01/2020', '26/01/2020', '26/01/2020', '29/01/2020', '29/01/2020',\n       ...\n       '05/01/2021', '05/01/2021', '05/01/2021', '05/01/2021', '05/01/2021',\n       '05/01/2021', '05/01/2021', '05/01/2021', '05/01/2021', '05/01/2021'],\n      dtype='object', length=9050)] are in the [column*s]"
```

I have tried to make the plot with and without converting `Report date` to datetime object, I tried substitute `x` value with all the columns in the data frame, but all give me the same error code.

Appreciate if anyone can help me to understand how to handle these issues here and going forward. I've spent hours to resolve it but cannot find the answers.

I did not encounter this issue before when I downloaded some notebooks and datasets from Kaggle to follow along.

Thank you and happy new year.

Comment: how about try converting it in np.ndarray by doing x.values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to assign the converted date back to the column:

```
confirm_df['Report_date'] = pd.to_datetime(confirm_df['Report_date'])
```

Second, When the `plot` method is called from a dataframe object, you need to provide only the column names as argument (1).

```
confirm_df.plot(x='Report_date', y='Case_classification')
```

But the above code still throws error because 'Case_classification' is not numeric data.

You are trying to plot datetime vs. categorical data, so normal plot won't work but Something like this could work (2):

```
# I used only first 15 examples here, full dataset is kinda messy
confirm_df.iloc[:15, :].groupby(['Report_date', 'Case_classification']).size().unstack().plot.bar()
```

[image]

(1)[pandas.DataFrame.plot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html)

(2)[How to plot categorical variable against a date column in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56050037/how-to-plot-categorical-variable-against-a-date-column-in-python)

Comment: it works and  thank you very much. So the issues is that I have to use the groupby to aggregate the item that i want to plot .

Answer (score 1):

Several problems. First, the links were incorrect, I have edited them (probably just a copy/paste error). Second, you have to assign the converted datetime series back to the dataframe. Use `print(confirm_df.dtypes)` to see the difference. <s>Then, the dataset is not ordered by date, but matplotlib expects an ordered x-axis.</s> Well, actually, the problem was that the parser misinterpreted the datetime objects. I have added `dayfirst=True` to ensure that the dates are read correctly. Finally, what do you want to plot here? Just the cases by date? The number of cases per group by date? Your original code implies just the former but this is not really informative, is it?

```
import io
import pandas as pd
import requests
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

print("starting download")
confirm_resp = requests.get('https://api.data.gov.hk/v2/filter?q=%7B%22resource%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.chp.gov.hk%2Ffiles%2Fmisc%2Fenhanced_sur_covid_19_eng.csv%22%2C%22section%22%3A1%2C%22format%22%3A%22json%22%7D').content
print("finished download")

confirm_df = pd.read_json(io.StringIO(confirm_resp.decode('utf-8')))

confirm_df.columns = confirm_df.columns.str.replace(" ", "_")
confirm_df['Report_date'] = pd.to_datetime(confirm_df['Report_date'], dayfirst=True)
confirm_df.columns = ['Case_no', 'Report_date', 'Onset_date', 'Gender', 'Age', 
'Name_of_hospital_admitted', 'Status', 'Resident', 'Case_classification', 'Confirmed_probable']
confirm_df = confirm_df.drop('Name_of_hospital_admitted', axis = 1)

print(confirm_df.dtypes)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 5))
ax.plot(confirm_df['Report_date'], confirm_df['Case_classification'])
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Sample output:
[image]

Some grouping and data aggregation might be more informative, but you have to decide what you want to display first before writing the code.

Comment: I was typing and posting almost exactly the same answer with first and second ponits and all. Such coincidence, should i delete my post? :) I'm new so please guide.

Comment: If you add the output of your `groupby` approach, then the answer differs.

Comment: it works and thank you very much. Another new thing to me is the dayfirst argument.